# Lidando com eventos em elementos adicionados posteriormente

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Considere o seguinte HTML:

```html
<div id="div">
    <button class="foo">Botão1</button>
</div>
```

E o seguinte script:

```coffeescript
$(".foo").click ->
    alert "foobar"

$("#div").append '<button class="foo">Botão2</button>'
```

Rodem no JSFiddle e confiram: http://jsfiddle.net/dpa8rj8L/

No Botão1 o evento é disparado. No Botão2 não, pois ele foi adicionado depois.

Eu gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de tornar o evento disponível também para o segundo botão, se possível, sem ter que adicionar o evento "click" novamente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando o [elemento não existe no DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122150/jquery-selecting-elements-that-dont-yet-exist), tem que fazer a [delegação](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) do evento no `document`, ou num elemento mais próximo que englobe os `.foo`'s:

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.foo', function(e){ 
    alert('bar');
});
```

Comment: Funcionou. Versão atualizada do JSFiddle pra quem quiser conferir: http://jsfiddle.net/dpa8rj8L/7/

Comment: Só pra complementar a resposta, isso é a [delegação](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) de eventos no jQuery.

Comment: Valeu, @Danguilherme, atualizei a resposta com o link, *perfecto* :)