# Jquery não funciona com novos elementos HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, javascript-eventos

Tenho um formulário HTML com diversos elementos (inputs text, range, image, etc).
Quando clico num botão são adicionados dinamicamente outros elementos, mas nestes novos elementos, os eventos jquery não funcionam (onclick, onchange, etc).

Como posso corrigir isto?

Comment: Aqui na comunidade já existe perguntas assim, vou dar um procurada.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Lidando com eventos em elementos adicionados posteriormente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32175/lidando-com-eventos-em-elementos-adicionados-posteriormente), [Problemas com eventos em elementos criados dinamicamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25519/), tem mais [nessa pesquisa  feita no Google](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=jquery+events+em+elementos+adicionados+dinamicos+site:pt.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Não é que o jQuery não funcione, é que você inseriu o elemento após a renderização da página, significa que você tem que anexar os eventos que estarão vinculados ao mesmo após o ocorrido